# Login and registeration stopped working suddenly - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, register

In my store login and register just keep on refreshing
i have add the following lines in every register.phtml
after form tag

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> 

<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />**strong text**
```

but still not working !

`configuration/general/web/cookie settings`:

`Hhtp only :no`, `Cookie restriction :no`, `Time :86400`.

added these lines in login.phtml but still just refreshing

```
      <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

added theses lines in `accountController.php` in login post action but still issue exists the same

```
* Login post action
 */
public function loginPostAction(){

// generate form_key if missing or invalid
if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null))
        || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
    $this->getRequest()->setParams(array(
        'form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
    ));
}
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add this code `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` right after a `<form>` tag OR the second one but not both.

**EDIT:**

For your **loop problem**:

1) the `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />` you add it right after `<ul class="form-list">`

2) Update this query in your database: `update core_config_data set value = null where path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain'`

3) change in database: table: **core_config_data**, update **web/url/redirect_to_base** to 0 instead of 1

4) clean your Magento and navigator cache and session

Comment: :o thanks. i ll do that but login loop? it just keep on refreshing :(

Comment: check your code for errors, try to clean cache magento and navigator

Comment: i have done what u have suggested still both in loop refresh

Comment: registeration started working... login.phtml already have formkey and i m adding this <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        right after <ul class="form-list">  but login refresh is still the same

Comment: please look my edit

Comment: i dont have web/url/redirect_to_base in my core/config data should i add it? and what should i give it

Comment: No, dont add anything, go to `Under System > Configuration > Web > Url Options > Auto-redirect to Base URL`set it to `No`

Comment: still just keep on refreshing and customer login not working

Comment: Look my update.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I had tried your solution but still customer login and signup not working for me. Can you please suggest me here?